# PostgreSQL error witn Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm trying to make a request and I have an error when I'm using `LIKE` on the `created_at` field.
I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Eloquent (ORM).

```
$date = Carbon::now();
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
     $chart[$hour]['hour'] = $hour;
     $chart[$hour]['allowed'] = VisitsAllowed::where('created_at', 'LIKE', Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d %'))->count();
     $chart[$hour]['denied'] = VisitsDenied::where('created_at', 'LIKE', Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d %'))->count();
}
```

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~* unknown
LINE 1: ... aggregate from "visits_allowed" where "created_at" LIKE $1
^
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "visits_allowed" where "created_at" LIKE 2017-05-30 %)
```

Can someone help me to find a solution.

Comment: Can you give an example for $date?

Comment: Maybe try `'ILIKE'` instead of `'LIKE'`

Comment: ILIKE don't work too.

Comment: @TobiasBeuving $date = Carbon::now(); => 2017-05-30 11:57:37

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead :

```
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
     $chart[$hour]['hour'] = $hour;
     $chart[$hour]['allowed'] = VisitsAllowed::where('created_at', '=', Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d'))->count();
     $chart[$hour]['denied'] = VisitsDenied::where('created_at', '=', Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d'))->count();
}
```

Comment: Even with removing '%' from the format and add it next to it ?

Comment: You can't use 'LIKE' with a datetime, you can try with '=' instead

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution but testing if the date (say 2017-05-30) is between: yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 and yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59 works.

```
$chart[$hour]['allowed'] = VisitsAllowed::where('created_at',  '>=', Carbon::parse($date )->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at',  '<=', Carbon::parse($date )->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59')
            ->count();

$chart[$hour]['denied'] = VisitsDenied::where('created_at',  '>=', Carbon::parse($date )->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at',  '<=', Carbon::parse($date )->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59')
            ->count();
```